# twitter Bootstrap navbar links moves when page resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My Bootstrap navbar links including search goes away whenever I resize the page anywhere less than about 600px. What would be the cause of this? Only the logo does not move. The navbar is fine and does not resize, so I was surprised that the links went away when the page resize. I do not want any of my links to move from where they are regardless of page resizing.

code is here: HTML

http://jsfiddle.net/Crisp3333/2u0tgh5r/

```
<div class="menubar">
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="yancii_logo.jpg" width="40px" height="50px"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search events, places, contacts......" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="#">CreateEvent</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MyEvents</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: provide a demo code to understand the problem. You can use [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I provided the code, I have never used jsfiddle as an editor before, just used it as a reference, please be patient.

Comment: Bootstraps navbar collapses on screens smaller than 768px, see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar I think that might be your issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this piece of code: `/* min-width: 1400px; */`
And you can find it in your `class  ->  .navbar`

It basically causes your drop-down menu not to show. And the menu buttons don't resize along as you want them to.

Hope this helps you out!
Cheers

Comment: that's correct, the problem is caused by that min-width